# Format day of the week

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, what would a script look like that would identify days of the week (i.e., Monday, Wednesday, Friday) and then change the background color of the corresponding cells?

Comment: What's the cell content? Just 'monday', 'wednesday', 'friday', etc?

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with Conditional formatting (one rule per colour) where the data is dates:

[image: WA65640 example]

or if text, with Text contains `sunday` .... `saturday`.